# Is there a way to set a float variable = some number * a variable from a string

Tags: c++, string, casting

I have a string that the user inputs, for example: 4-x^2.

createReadableFunction takes in that string and outputs a string that changes the first letter, in this case x, to (a+x*d)

```
functionString = createReadableFunction(functionString);
cout << "Function is: " << functionString << endl;
```

So now the functionString is 4-(a+x*d)^2

I want this string to define a float such as

```
_function = std::atof(functionString.c_str());
```

However, this function simply sets _function as 4 rather than 4-(a+x*d)^2

**tldr;** I want a float to be defined like _function = 4-(a+x*d)^2, but by converting a string to the float.

Comment: C++ isn't JavaScript. There's no such thing like expression evaluation from strings.

Comment: So there is no way to accomplish this?

Comment: No, unless you write a parser and evaluate the parsed expression yourself. But that's far too much than being explained in a few paragraphs here.

Comment: Maybe using some LLVM library you can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested, you actually want to evaluate mathematical expressions. This cannot be done out of the box in C++, but there are parsers/evaluators like [this one](https://fastmathparser.codeplex.com/), which can help you achieve what you want.

Give it a try and come back with a trial code, if something goes wrong.